# I want to display subject for specific class i.e A or B but current I display only A?

Tags: php

I try to display every each data on the specific td, but I dont know where to fix my code. Please check the screenshop below to understand the clearly problems. Please any help to solve this problems.

```
   <table class="table table-hover table-bordered ">

        <tr><th>Day</th><th colspan="2">08:00-08:40</th><th colspan="2">8:40-09:20</th><th colspan="2">09:20-10:00</th><th>10:00-10:15</th><th colspan="2">10:15-10:55</th><th colspan="2">10:55-11:35</th><th colspan="2">11:35-12:15</th><th>12:15-01:15</th><th colspan="2">01:15-01:55</th><th colspan="2">01:55-02:35</th></tr>

<?php 

    $timesVariants = array("08:00-08:40", "08:40-09:20", "09:20-10:00", "10:00-10:15", "10:15-10:55", "10:55-11:35", "11:35-12:15", "12:15-01:15", "01:15-01:55","01:55-02:35");

$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM timetable,classroom,subprogramme WHERE classroom.classid = timetable.classid AND subprogramme.subid = timetable.subid";
    $res = $connect->query($sqlquery);

$classes = array();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
   $classes[$row['day']][$row['tid']][$row['time']] = array('courseid'=> $row['cid'], 'classname' => $row['classname'], 'subname' => $row['subname']);
}

//This is a loop
foreach($classes as $day => $daySchedule) {
 foreach($daySchedule as $teacher) {

    print '<tr>';
    print "<td>$day</td>";
    foreach($timesVariants as $time) {
      if (empty($teacher[$time])){

             print "<td>*</td><td>*</td>";
      }


      else{

          print '<td>' . $teacher[$time]['courseid'] . '</td><td>' . $teacher[$time]['subname'] . ''. $teacher[$time]['classname'] . '</td>';
      }

    } 
    print '</tr>';
 }
}

?>
</table>
```

Output

[Results display on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CStZB.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <?php

        if(isset($_POST["tid"])){

            $tid = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST["tid"]);


         $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM timetable,classroom,subprogramme WHERE classroom.classid = timetable.classid AND subprogramme.subid = timetable.subid AND timetable.tid = ".$tid." ORDER BY timetable.timid ASC";
        $res = $connect->query($sqlquery);

            if($res->num_rows > 0){


        ?>

            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

            <tr><th>Day</th><th colspan="2">8:00-8:40</th><th colspan="2">8:40-9:20</th><th colspan="2">9:20-10:00</th><th colspan="2">10:00-10:15</th><th colspan="2">10:15-10:55</th><th colspan="2">10:55-11:35</th><th colspan="2">11:35-12:15</th><th colspan="2">12:15-1:15</th><th colspan="2">1:15-1:55</th><th colspan="2">1:55-2:35</th></tr>
    <?php 


        $timesVariants = array("8:00-8:40", "8:40-9:20", "9:20-10:00", "10:00-10:15", "10:15-10:55", "10:55-11:35", "11:35-12:15", "12:15-01:15", "1:15-1:55","1:55-2:35");

    $classes = array();
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
       $classes[$row['day']][$row['tid']][$row['time']] = array('courseid'=> $row['cid'], 'classname' => $row['classname'], 'subname' => $row['subname']);
    }

    //This is a loop
    foreach($classes as $day => $daySchedule) {
     foreach($daySchedule as $teacher) {

        print '<tr>';
        print "<td>$day</td>";
        foreach($timesVariants as $time) {
          if (empty($teacher[$time])){

                 print "<td>*</td><td>*</td>";
          }


          else{

              print '<td>' . $teacher[$time]['courseid'] . '</td><td>' . $teacher[$time]['subname'] . ''. $teacher[$time]['classname'] . '</td>';
          }

        } 
        print '</tr>';
     }
    }

    ?>
    </table>

    <?php 
                }

            else{ print "<div class='alert alert-danger col-md-4'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Not yet set timetable</div>"; }
        } ?>
    </div>

The problems was on td I forgot to put colspan = 2, and other problem on sql query I forgot to inner join the tables in order to get all right that i want to display on the page.
```

Answer (score 0):

You trouble is in the GROUP BY. MySql have no strict restrictions (by default) that each column should use aggregation function, so the result is the first row, instead of complicating SQL use PHP, your result seems not to be huge, so another loop will not affect performance:

```
$timesVariants = array("08:00-08:40", "08:40-09:20", "09:20-10:00", "10:00-10:15", "10:15-10:55", "10:55-11:35", "11:35-12:15", "12:15-1:15", "01:15-01:55","01:55-02:35");

$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM timetable";

$classes = array();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
   $classes[$row['day']][$row['tid']][$row['time']] = array('subject'=> $row['subject'], 'class' => $row['class'], 'progid' => $row['progid']);
}

//This is a loop
foreach($classes as $day => $daySchedule) {
 foreach($daySchedule as $teacher) {

    print '<tr>';
    print "<td>$day</td>";
    foreach($timesVariants as $time) {
      if (empty($teacher[$time]))
         print "<td>None</td><td>None</td>";
      else
         print '<td>' . $teacher[$time]['subject'] . '</td><td>' . $teacher[$time]['class'] . '</td>';
    } 
    print '</tr>';
 }
}
```

Comment: @2oppion  Errors occurs on $timesVariants, $classes

Comment: @Erick, I havn't put it even in editor to check, but wasn't you able to add semicolon, and determine that "$row" was undefined?),  updated the answer)

Comment: @2oppion, I don't know exactly where to fix this ,  $timesVariants = [];
$classes = [];
$classes[$rows['day']][$rows['tid']][$rows['time']] = 
     ['subject' => $rows['subject'], 'class' => $rows['class'], 'progid' => $rows['progid']]; This three areas show red mark on dreamweaver.

Comment: in a console type 'php -l yourphp.php', to know if there is error. afer I've edited answer there is no "$rows" variable, there is "$row", and maybe dreamwaver don't know syntax of php >= 5.4,  in php older versions you can't use [] to define arrays, only array(), so replace  $classes = [] to $classes = array()

Comment: please look attached picture above. Some of changes I made is $classes = array(); but still errors remains(I using dreamweaver CS6).

Comment: on your screenshot $classes not updated? assuming it's "array()" issue, what is your PHP version? btw updated.

Comment: I agree that dreamweaver cs6 doesn't support. I try to run on the browser but result is quite differ. Lets screenshot the results

Comment: Hi @2oppin, please I want to add program from your solutions but I failed can you help to add. i.e |Chem| III-A | PHY | IV-B|.... according to time. Plz check picture above.